# list of file downloaded by wget

Tags: centos, wget, scp

I'm using wget in my centos server to download files through Internet. Sometimes I copy file to server by scp. I'm looking command that shows me list of file that was downloaded recently or even all files. So my question is, how to do this?

Comment: Is the `ls` command you are looking for?

Comment: how ls can me help? I'm looking for something that will show me the list of all downloaded files from Internet.

Comment: The files itself do not have any attribute that would say "I was downloaded from the Internet". It is up to you to filter what you want to select (for example by downloading to separate directory). The `ls` will simply list that files what you have chosen. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: in the browser you have Show All Downloads, are you want to say me that in centos, wget is nothing similar to this?

Comment: No. Browsers are huge programs with databases and history of downloaded files. `wget` is simple program that just does the download. Downloading files into a single dedicated directory can be a good practice if you want to have some order in them.

Comment: Simple : `grep wget .bash_history`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` downloads :

```
grep wget .bash_history
```

`grep` will print all lines containing the word 'wget' from the users `.bash_history` file.

`.bash_history` is a text file with the latest 1000 commands. (Example  default settings, can vary.)

See `/home/[user-name]/.bash_history`

Comment: Can you give more information to help other users understand

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Else : Use Google https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=bash_history